# How to find the numbers in the list with a value smaller than first number (head)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to define a function `smaller` which finds all the numbers in
a list which are smaller than the first number in the same list.

For example, `smaller [5, 7, 1, 2, 3]` should return `[1, 2, 3]`.

This is my code:

```
smaller :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
smaller [] = []
smaller (x:xs) = smaller [a | a <- xs, a <= x)
```

Anyone can help/guide me ?

Comment: Carsten's answer below is perfect. For thinking about where your ideas went wrong, it might be worth also wondering how you'd do it with direct recursion. The reason I say this is because I suspect you almost had the right idea, so it probably pays to see how it might have been right. :) You could try, instead of the bottom line, `smaller [x] = []` and `smaller (x:y:xs) = if (y < x) then y:(smaller (x:xs)) else smaller (x:xs)`

Comment: A neater way could be to have a helper method (maybe `smaller'`) which, given an `x` and a list returns a sublist of the elements less than `x`. The recursion for such a method will look a little neater, and then `smaller (x:xs) = smaller' x xs` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey you basically had it - just change the last `)` to `]` and remove the `smaller` (why do you want to make the list ever smaller?)

```
smaller :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
smaller [] = []
smaller (x:xs) = [a | a <- xs, a < x]
```

to make this more clear - the way you had it was that you got:

- `[1,2,3]` from `[5,7,1,2,3]` in the first step
- then reapplied `smaller` to get `[]` from `[1,2,3]` in the second
- applied `smaller` again to `[]` to get your final `[]` ;)

---

also if you want only elements smaller than `x` then it should be `a < x` instead of `x <= a` - your example is not clear on that but the topic want's `<`

---

in case you don't like *list-comprehensions* here is the same using `filter`:

```
smaller :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
smaller [] = []
smaller (x:xs) = filter (< x) xs
```

Comment: My error in syntax & in my thinking i used recursive to compare first number with remaining numbers......may be something wrong about list comprehension. i'm a newbie..
Thanks for your help!
---Resolved

Comment: hey no problem - btw: if it does what you want you should probably accept this - the *--Resolved--* comment sadly won't show (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Carsten's answer is just right, but it's worth noting that a more idiomatic solution is this, using the `filter` function instead of a comprehension:

```
smaller :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
smaller [] = []
smaller (a:as) = filter (<=a) as
```

Exercise: write your own version of the `filter` function.  Don't use comprehensions.  Signature:

```
-- | Return a list of the elements that satisfy the condition 
-- specified by the first argument, in the same order as they
-- appear in the original.
--
-- Some test cases to check whether you're doing it right:
--
-- > filter (\_ -> True) [1..10] == [1..10]
-- > filter (\_ -> False) [1..10] == []
-- > filter even [1..10] == [2,4,6,8,10]
--
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```